# magento 2.4 customer login time increase up to 1 year or more

Tags: customer, magento2.4, customer-account, login, customer-session

i want to my customer login time increase when he is one time logged in after when he/she open browser it must logged in

and i have below settings increased but not affecting in my store

Go to `System > Configuration > Web > Session Cookie Management` and set Cookie Lifetime

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**According to Magento's Official Docs**

*The lifetime of a customer shopping session is determined by several factors, including the length of the server session, the use of a persistent cart, and the lifetime of information that is stored in the browser. Although these are related to the same customer experience, they are actually separate processes with different expiration events and lifetimes.*

**Configure the cookie lifetime**

1. On the Admin sidebar, go to **Stores** > Settings > **Configuration**.
2. If you have multiple stores, set the **Store View** chooser in the upper-right corner to the store where the configuration applies.
   3.In the left panel under General, choose Web.
   [image]

Reference : https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/customers/customer-online-options.html